# OpenID, Maintain Login between browsers

Tags: c#, openid, intuit-partner-platform

I need to maintain an OpenID login between two different browsers (i.e. Chrome and IE). How can this be done?

I am using this code:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0300_Windows_Azure_Program_for_Intuit_Anywhere/0001_Installing_the_Windows_Azure_SDK_2.0_for_Intuit_Anywhere

Here is my code:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Action Result for Index, This flow will create OAuthConsumer Context using Consumer key and Consuler Secret key
    /// obtained when Application is added at intuit workspace. It creates OAuth Session out of OAuthConsumer and Calls 
    /// Intuit Workpsace endpoint for OAuth.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Redirect Result.</returns>
    public RedirectResult Index()
    {
        oauth_callback_url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oauth_callback_url"];
        consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"];
        consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"];
        oauthLink = Constants.OauthEndPoints.IdFedOAuthBaseUrl;
        IToken token = (IToken)Session["requestToken"];
        IOAuthSession session = CreateSession();
        IToken requestToken = session.GetRequestToken();
        Session["requestToken"] = requestToken;
        RequestToken = requestToken.Token;
        TokenSecret = requestToken.TokenSecret;

        oauthLink = Constants.OauthEndPoints.AuthorizeUrl + "?oauth_token=" + RequestToken + "&oauth_callback=" + UriUtility.UrlEncode(oauth_callback_url);
        return Redirect(oauthLink);
    }
```

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="oauth_callback_url" value="/OauthResponse"/>
<add key="menuProxy" value="MenuProxy"/>
<add key="grantUrl" value="OauthGrant"/>
<add key="qbo_base_url" value="https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/rest/user/v2/"/>

<!-- Enter the Application Name by replacing YourAppName -->
<add key="openid_identifier" value="https://openid.intuit.com/Identity-YourAppName"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to map the openid with the oauth tokens obtained for that user and persist this in a store. The next time the user logs in you should build logic within your application to lookup the tokens for that user (based on openid).